# calling mono command from php web service

Tags: c#, php, mono

I'm trying to call mono from a php site.  As a simple example to see how this actually works, I have a simple C# Console application that just writes "Hello World."  In my php endpoint, I do this:

```
    $command = "/opt/mono-3.2.1/bin/mono /opt/test/HelloWorld.exe";
    shell_exec($command);
```

I've also tried exec($command).  When I hit this endpoint, I do not see anything printed to the console.  That's what I assume is supposed to happen, but am not sure since I have never done anything like this or have ever used mono.  I know if I go to Terminal and do

```
mono HelloWorld.exe
```

then I do get "Hello World" in that Terminal window.  But from the web service, I don't get thrown an error, but I don't see anything launched or printed anywhere.

Am I calling mono correctly?  Is a Terminal window supposed to open up and print "Hello World"?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting and error displaying for PHP?

Comment: @knittl No how do I do that?

Comment: `error_reporting(~0);` in your script and `display_errors On` in your `php.ini` file

Answer (score 0):

Do you explicitely display the output of the command? Did you try something like:

```
$command = "/opt/mono-3.2.1/bin/mono /opt/test/HelloWorld.exe";
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

Did you try to redirect all the outputs from mono :

```
$command = "/opt/mono-3.2.1/bin/mono /opt/test/HelloWorld.exe 2>&1"
```

Does the user account running PHP have permissions to traverse and open your Mono app paths (both `/opt/mono-3.2.1/bin/mono`and `/opt/test/HelloWorld.exe`) ?

No, a terminal window is not supposed to open up when executing mono from your PHP script.